# Make array of line 1 from all txt files

Tags: php, arrays

I have a folder with .txt files that have info about songs. These files and lines are in an array made by this code:

```
$lyrics = glob('covers_info/*.txt');
foreach ($lyrics as $i => $file) {
$contents = file($file);
echo "<td class='notwrap bars' align='right' style='background-size:" . $time_seconds/10 . "px 100%;'>" . trim($contents[1]) . "</td>";
output more stuff here
}
```

Line one in the .txt files contain the song length in MM:SS format. I have converted this to seconds with this code:

```
$str_time = trim($contents[1]);
sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
$time_seconds = isset($seconds) ? $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds : $hours * 60 + $minutes;
```

Works fine.

I'm trying to use that to get total playing time below the table.

I think array_sum() is the way to go, but I don't know how.

Page: http://flamencopeko.net/covers.php.

Source: http://flamencopeko.net/covers.txt.

Comment: Why don't you just create a "totalTime" variable which you initialize to zero, then add the time each time you go around the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the time using variable itself no need to go for array here.

```
$lyrics = glob('covers_info/*.txt');
$total_sec = 0;
foreach ($lyrics as $i => $file) {
$contents = file($file);
$str_time = trim($contents[1]);
sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
$time_seconds = isset($seconds) ? $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds : $hours * 60 + $minutes;
$total_sec += $time_seconds;
echo "<td class='notwrap bars' align='right' style='background-size:" . $time_seconds/10 . "px 100%;'>" . trim($contents[1]) . "</td>";
output more stuff here
}
```

You can use **$total_sec** variable to retrieve total time.

Comment: Thanks. This one says 3762 seconds (01:02:42). I'm pretty sure that's right. Awesome. Super thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$lyrics = glob('covers_info/*.txt');
$count = 0;
foreach ($lyrics as $i => $file) {
    $count += $time_seconds;
    $contents = file($file);
    echo "<td class='notwrap bars' align='right' style='background-size:" . $time_seconds/10 . "px 100%;'>" . trim($contents[1]) . "</td>";
    // output more stuff here
}
echo "Total song time: ".$time_seconds; // Format as you wish
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to implement this, but only got 232 which is the length of the last song (03:52).

Answer (score 0):

I also need to format the echo to hh:mm:ss format. None of the examples I found seem to work.

Comment: Found a solution: `Total playing time: <?php echo (secondsToTime($ss)); ?>.`